# How to set an image as a cursor in if statement in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image, cursor

I have the following code:

```
if (conditions) {
    [NSCursor pop];
    [[NSCursor closedHandCursor] push];
}
```

So if the conditions in the if loop are true, my cursor will change to a closedHandCursor.
Now I want to change it with an image. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following initializer to init NSCursor:

```
- (id)initWithImage:(NSImage *)newImage hotSpot:(NSPoint)aPoint
```

Present in NSCursor Class and let me know , if it helps...

Comment: could not vote yesterday, didn't had enough rep points that moment :) vote is submitted now